# error message when running zenity under 16.04: Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged

Tags: gui, gtk, zenity

Under ubuntu 16.04 I get the following message

```
 Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged
```

when I open zenity with the command

```
  zenity --text-info --filename=<filename>
```

This didn't happen under 14.04.     I presume that the answer is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883211/gtkdialog-mapped-without-a-transient-parent) but the post doesn't explain how to implement the proposed solution.     Could somebody please explain which file I should add the suggested lines to?

> You fix this warning by giving the GtkDialog a parent to be modal to.
>   The relevant functions are gtk_window_set_transient_for() (which sets
>   this window to always be on top of, or transient for, another one) and
>   optionally gtk_window_set_modal() to make it a modal dialog. This is
>   ultimately what the various GtkDialog constructors do.

Comment: `zenity --help-general` gives `--attach=WINDOW    Set the parent window to attach to` but I'm not sure how to use it (what is Window?), perhaps it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Al.G.  I was able to recover the  WINDOW id with the line       `WINDOW_ID=$(xprop -name `echo $TITLE` | grep WM_CLIENT_LEADER | cut -d"#" -f2 | cut -c2-20)`      and I then tried      `zenity --attach=$WINDOW_ID --text-info --filename=<filename>`    but sadly I still got the warning.    Too bad, but it may come in handy one day to know how to get the window id!

Comment: Actually if you search [the source](https://github.com/GNOME/zenity/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=gtk_window_set_transient_for&type=Code) of zenity for gtk_window_set_transient_for you'll get no results.

Comment: Yup.     If you search for gtk_window_set_modal you get lots of results, but I don't know how to set it in a way that silences the message.

Comment: According to the docs you give it a window and a parent window. I suppose it should be called somewhere after the window creation with parent window set to `NULL`. However I couldn't `make install` zenity locally (I couldn't find docs or something on how to configure install) so I finaly gave up. Will have to use the dirty `2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Ignore it.**

It's a **warning**, not an error. The application works, it's just not coded with best practices in mind, as it seems. You would have to modify `zenity`'s source code to implement the fix described in your linked question and then compile it yourself, but... it works anyway, so why should you bother?

If you just want to get rid of the output in your terminal, you could simply redirect STDERR (standard error stream, that's where the warning gets printed to) to `/dev/null` (virtual character device that swallows data) by appending `2> /dev/null` to the end of the command, like this:

```
zenity --text-info --filename=<filename> 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks!    Unfortunately for some reason `2> /dev/null` doesn't have the desired effect, the warning still persists.    I know it's only a nuisance, but I would love to be able to suppress warnings like this.

Comment: I still think the people from zenity should fix this. Its very annoying.

Comment: It clutters the output and makes it hard to notice new errors. Even worse, if we redirect stderr to /dev/null. Errors should be fixed, not covered.

Comment: OMG!! I'm too late to this party!!!
Works like a charm!!!! Besides it IS just warning not error and as long is not popping up on my dialogues I'm content! THAAAAANKS!!!

Answer (score 11):

It seems that the Gtk devs decided to add this warning which affects a number of packages. We just have to wait for the Zenity dev to catch up and fix Zenity.

With the **bash** shell (this is not Posix-compliant) it's relatively simple to suppress specific error messages while allowing other messages through to stderr:

```
zenity --info --text "hello" 2> >(grep -v 'GtkDialog' >&2)
```

This does not interfere with stdout, so that may be piped or used in command substitution as normal:

```
echo message: $(zenity --entry  2> >(grep -v 'GtkDialog' >&2) )
```

Comment: I just have to say, Dave: that's a pretty nifty use of redirection. Bravo.

Answer (score 3):

`zenity ... 2>/dev/null` works for me. The only problem I see is that other (important) errors messages will also be suppressed so better build error capture somehow in your code

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a dangerous solution.  Better not use it.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Dave Rove's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1075318/351528), if you have many prompts, you could clean this up by creating a function such as

```
function zenityNoWarn() {
    zenity "$@" 2> >(grep -v 'GtkDialog' >&2)
}
```

then use it like this:

```
zenityNoWarn --question --text "Are you sure?"
```

This makes things a little easier to read when combining with other logic:

```
if [[ `zenityNoWarn --question --text "Are you sure?"; echo $?` -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Yes!"
else
    echo "No..."
fi
```