# How do I suppress GtkDialog warnings in zenity and yad using Bash redirection in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I'm trying to suppress `GtkDialog` warnings in `zenity` and `yad`:

```bash
$ zenity --error --text hello
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Error redirection and filtering works:

```bash
$ zenity --error --text hello 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)
```

**YEAH...** Annoying warning message disappears!!

This can be placed in `~/.bashrc` for development work as answered here:

- [How to make zenity “transient parent” warning disappear permanently (using function)](https://askubuntu.com/a/896940/307523)

and here:

- [How to make zenity “transient parent” warning disappear permanently (using alias)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110850/307523)

When creating a script for others to use though, you don't want the burden of them changing their `~/.bashrc`.

---

I'm having trouble creating a typing shortcut for: `2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)` to be used inside script.

For many reasons variable assignment `GTK_SPAM="2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)"` followed later by variable usage `"$GTK_SPAM"` doesn't work.

`alias zenity="zenity 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)"` before calling script works  but, I can't use this within a script.

Using an array to hold the typing shortcut isn't working:

```bash
$ aGtkSpam=(2\> \>\(grep -v GtkDialog \>\&2\))

$ DumpArray "${aGtkSpam[@]}"
Array Elements:
0: 2>
1: >(grep
2: -v
3: GtkDialog
4: >&2)

$ zenity --error --text hello "${aGtkSpam[@]}"
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

$ yad --text hello 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)

$ yad --text hello "${aGtkSpam[@]}"
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

I found many excellent generic answers on word-splitting and parameters which ***should*** solve my problem but a specific syntax eludes me.

***Any clues?***

Comment: Can't you just redirect stderr for the duration of the script using `exec`? Something like `exec 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)`

Comment: @steeldriver you mean use that command on second line after the `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: anywhere before where you want to start filtering the stream - doesn't have to be right after the shebang

Comment: steeldriver's suggestion is good and works in  interactive shells as well.   @steeldriver I would recommend making an answer out of that.

Comment: Array may have to be unquoted for this to work

Comment: @steeldriver Your idea is an elegant solution and turns my question into an XY problem. It also fixes both `yad` and `zenity` plus other apps I image all at once. Please post an answer for me to accept.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've posted an answer but note that it is largely untested - please use with caution

Comment: @dessert It's a lot of awkward typing to remember and not as readable as "$NoSpamMsg" every time `yad` is used in your script.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy removing the quotes around `${aGtkSpam[@]}` did not help but it was a good idea. Jarno pointed that out a couple of years ago on a different script and it worked then. See my comment below SteelDriver's answer for my more targeted solution that allows other GtkDialog errors to flow through.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think syntax alone can help you here - because of the order in which the shell sets up redirections and expands variables. To give a very simple illustration:

```
$ arr=( ">" "/dev/null" )
$ set -x
$ echo foo "${arr[@]}"
+ echo foo '>' /dev/null
foo > /dev/null
```

i.e. everything has been expanded "correctly", but `> /dev/null` has simply become a list of string arguments passed to `echo`.

You *could* force evaluation using `eval`:

```
$ eval echo foo "${arr[@]}"
+ eval echo foo '>' /dev/null
++ echo foo
```

but really it would be better to redirect the stream for the duration of your script using `exec`:

```
exec 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)
```

or, if you want to be able to turn the filter off before the end of the script, then based on [After using `exec 1>file`, how can I stop this redirection of the STDOUT to file and restore the normal operation of STDOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25475268/4440445) it should be possible to do

```
exec 3>&2 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)
```

and then later

```
exec 2>&3 3>&-
```

to recover the duplicated stream.

Comment: I haven't tested everything but `exec 2> >(grep -v 'GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent' >&2)` in script before using `yad` works fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 7):

You can define and use aliases in your script if you set the `expand_aliases` shell option, e.g.:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias zenity='zenity 2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)'
…
```

Now every `zenity` line behaves as if `2> >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)` were added and you can disable this behaviour as usual by prepending a backslash or `command`:

```bsh
\zenity        # and
command zenity
```

both ignore the alias.

#### Further reading

- [Why doesn't my Bash script recognize aliases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1496/246819)

Comment: Although upvoting your answer I'm still using SteelDriver's answer for the time-being. Your answer did inspire me to use `shopt -u expand_aliases` so aliases cannot create unstable environment for my script. In other words, turn off all the user's aliases so the script doesn't behave erratically.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That’s not necessary, as “Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive” – if you didn’t set the option before in your script it’s no use.

Answer (score 6):

You can use function in the script. `zenity` and `yad` have useful info in stdout, so I suggest to redirect just stderr to `/dev/null`

```
#/bin/bash

zen_nospam() {
  zenity "$@" 2&>1 >(grep -v GtkDialog >&2)
}

zen_nospam --error --text hello
```

btw function can be defined in .bashrc if needed in command line, not script

Comment: Your answer is sort of where I started from: https://askubuntu.com/a/1110850/307523 and https://askubuntu.com/a/896940/307523

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Please add all this information to your question!

Comment: @dessert I added this to question introduction but perhaps it could be worded better.