# 18.04: Run zenity in background or not show the terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, zenity, background-process

A .desktop file runs some dialog boxes using [zenity](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/zenity.1.html) ([more](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/)) on an Ubuntu 18.04 system.

I want just the zenity dialog boxes to come up, not the terminal. I've tried setting the Terminal tag to false and running it without the Terminal tag.

I feel like this is a question that should have already been asked on here but I can't seem to find anything on this.

Edit: I'm running zenity version 3.28.1
Also I'm getting a warning "Gtk-Message: 13:03:17.218: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged." when I call a zenity command.
I thought maybe that was making the terminal pop up so I tried sending the warning to /dev/null, but the terminal is still popping up.

Edit 2: I think the issue could be related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844323/error-message-when-running-zenity-under-16-04-gtk-message-gtkdialog-mapped-wit?rq=1) post but there doesn't seem to be any solution to his problem either.

Comment: The version of Zenity may be significant. Would you mind clicking [edit] and letting us know which of the 16 different releases https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/ you're using?

Comment: Also show us examples of commands you tried, what happened and what you wanted to happen. `.desktop` file example is also important.

Answer (score 0):

The next tried on 19.10 with 3.32.0-4 version of zenity.

Modified my Viber's `.desktop` file the next way:

```
$ cp ~/.local/share/applications/Viber.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/runzenity.desktop

$ gedit .local/share/applications/runzenity.desktop

[Desktop Entry]
Name=ZenScript
Comment=Calendar showing
Exec=/home/user/test/zenscript.sh
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Created `~/test/zenscript.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/zenity --calendar
```

Made it executable: `chmod +x ~/test/zenscript.sh`.

ZenScript application icon appeared in main menu. After clicking it calendar opens without a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just put  `&` at the end of the `Exec=....`  line.